# Replacing words matching regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, output, nltk, ontology

```
import re
replacement_patterns = [
(r'won\'t', 'will not'),
(r'can\'t', 'cannot'),
(r'i\'m', 'i am'),
(r'ain\'t', 'is not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ll', '\g<1> will'),
(r'(\w+)n\'t', '\g<1> not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ve', '\g<1> have'),
(r'(\w+)\'s', '\g<1> is'),
(r'(\w+)\'re', '\g<1> are'),
(r'(\w+)\'d', '\g<1> would')
 ]
class RegexpReplacer(object):

   def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):
      self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl)          
                      in pattern]
   def replace(self, text):
      s = text
      for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
          (s, count) = re.subn(pattern, repl, s)
   return s


 rep=RegexpReplacer()
 print rep.replace("can't is a contradicton")
```

I have copied this code from Python Text Processing with NLTK 2.0 Cookbook by Jacob Perkins

However my expected output is:
cannot is a contradiction

Actual Output is:
can't is a contradiction

I'm unable to pinpoint the error in t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some indentation issues and typos - I'm not quite sure how the interpreter was giving you any output at all.  After I fixed those, I got your expected output.

```
import re
replacement_patterns = [
(r'won\'t', 'will not'),
(r'can\'t', 'cannot'),
(r'i\'m', 'i am'),
(r'ain\'t', 'is not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ll', '\g<1> will'),
(r'(\w+)n\'t', '\g<1> not'),
(r'(\w+)\'ve', '\g<1> have'),
(r'(\w+)\'s', '\g<1> is'),
(r'(\w+)\'re', '\g<1> are'),
(r'(\w+)\'d', '\g<1> would')
 ]
class RegexpReplacer(object):

   def __init__(self, patterns=replacement_patterns):

      # Fixed this line - "patterns", not "pattern"
      self.patterns = [(re.compile(regex), repl) for (regex, repl) in patterns]

   def replace(self, text):
      s = text
      for (pattern, repl) in self.patterns:
          (s, count) = re.subn(pattern, repl, s)

      # Fixed indentation here
      return s


rep=RegexpReplacer()
print rep.replace("can't is a contradicton")
```

Comment: Thanks :) Can you explain this line  (s, count) = re.subn(pattern, repl, s). More specifically what's meant by (s,count)?

Comment: @AnkitaPrasad `re.subn` returns a two-element tuple - the first element is the resulting string after the substitutions have been made, the second element is the count of how many substitutions were made.  In the context of your `replace` method, `(s, count) = re.subn(...` means that you are assigning the first element of the returned tuple to `s` (the string) and the second element of the returned tuple (the number of substitutions) to `count`.  Since `count` goes unused, you could equivalently use `s = re.sub(pattern, repl, s)`

Answer (score 0):

*Either* use raw strings *or* escape the quotation marks, but not both.

```
>>> print r'won\'t'
won\'t
>>> print 'won\'t'
won't
```

or, if you prefer raw strings:

```
>>> print r"won't"
won't
```

Comment: Thanks. But your solution only worked for the won't and not for can't, i'm etc.